# ng-animate causing flicker on iOS

Tags: css, angularjs, css-animations, ng-animate

I am trying to slide a side navigation menu in and out using ng-animate. It is working well except there is an initial flicker of the menu in its final state before it slides in. Here is the CSS:

```
&.ng-enter,
&.ng-leave-active {
  @include translate(-100%, 0)
}

&.ng-enter-active {
  @include translate(0, 0);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I've run into this before and what did the trick for me was adding

```
-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
```

I've also had success by adding

```
-webkit-transform:translate3d(0,0,0);
```

and also

```
-webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
```

for something similar.

So you could test one or all 3 like :

```
.myAnimElement {
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -webkit-transform:translate3d(0,0,0);
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
}
```

(Just be sure to take off the ones you are not using) Hope these help!

Edit: a little googling has shown other people have found this to be the fix

```
 -webkit-perspective: 1000;
 -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
```

So you might try this as well if the previous answers do not work.

Comment: where did you add these to?

Comment: @compsci45000 on whatever element you are animating

Comment: Thanks for the help but still getting the same result

Comment: @compsci45000 are you using javascript as well? What does the translate mixin look like exactly? If you can throw your example code in a fiddle, it would be a little easier to help.